# How to validate/match data from different files in C#

Tags: c#, csv, filestream, streamreader

I'm creating a fake flight tracker for a project and need to check that the sum of lines in a Flight.csv file (all the individual flights) matches a the numOfFlights variable in an Airport.csv file. How can I cross-examine this data from the two files w/out having to merge them?

Here is relevant code, lmk if more is necessary to figuring out the problem.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Flight[] flight = new Flight[1000];
        Airport[] airport = new Airport[1000];
        int flightCount = 0;
        int airportCount = 0;

        ReadFlightFile(ref flight, ref flightCount);
        ReadAirportFile(ref airport, ref airportCount);

        int numRecords = flightCount;            

        OutputFlightMenu();
        string userInput = "----";
        while (userInput != "exit")
        {
            userInput = ReadLine().ToLower();
            Clear();
            OutputFlightMenu();
            switch (userInput)
            {
                case "passengers":
                    //Stuff
                    break;
                case "time":
                    //Stuff
                    break;
                case "average":
                    //Stuff
                    break;
                case "sub":
                    OutputSubMenu();
                    string userInput2 = "----";
                    while (userInput2 != "quit")
                    {
                        userInput2 = ReadLine().ToLower();
                        Clear();
                        OutputSubMenu();
                        switch (userInput2)
                        {
                            case "flight":
                                //Stuff
                                break;
                            case "count":
                                //Stuff
                                break;
                            case "airline":
                                //Stuff
                                break;
                            default:
                                WriteLine("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("====Exiting System===");
                    break;
                case "report":
                    //Stuff
                    break;
                default:
                    WriteLine("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        Clear();
        WriteLine("=====Goodbye=====");
        ReadKey();

    }

    public static void ReadFlightFile(ref Flight[] flight, ref int flightCount)
    {
        string path = "Flight.csv";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] flightArray = line.Split(',');

            flight[flightCount] = new Flight(int.Parse(flightArray[0]), flightArray[1], int.Parse(flightArray[2]),
                int.Parse(flightArray[3]), int.Parse(flightArray[4]));

            flightCount++;

        }

    }
    //Basic Read Method
    public static void ReadAirportFile(ref Airport[] airport, ref int airportCount)
    {
        string path = "Airport.csv";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] airportArray = line.Split(',');

            airport[airportCount] = new Airport(int.Parse(airportArray[0]), airportArray[1], airportArray[2], 
                int.Parse(airportArray[3]), DateTime.Parse(airportArray[4]));

            airportCount++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the data from the respective files:

Flight.csv:

3446,Delta,91,120,120

2789,United,34,56,78

9078,American,200,240,210

9079,American,67,156,165

4567,Southwest,89,89,91

6799,Delta,95,67,55

1265,United,102,187,175

8421,American,12,191,191

3332,Southwest,78,45,44

Airport.csv:

9000,ATL,Atlanta,9,12/9/2017

As you can see, the numOfFlights element in the airport array (9) DOES match the sum of the flights.

For the intents of this project, I already know that the data will match, but I need to be able to validate that.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: `As you can see, the numOfFlights element in the airport array (9) DOES match the sum of the flights.` I can't see that. Can you break down how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: just compare your `numOfFlights` with `flightCount`

Comment: Please explain *in words* what you're trying to do. "cross-examine the data" doesn't mean anything, and it's not at all clear from your code what your intentions are. Is there a problem with your code? Does it crash or not compile, or what?

Comment: @mjwills Certainly! The fourth element in the Airport.csv (9) matches the literal total # of flights in the Flight.csv.

Comment: Is there only one Airport record in the file? What if there are more? If there can't be more, why use an array?

Answer (score 0):

`airport.Where(o=>o.numOfFlights==flightCount)` will return the airports that has the numOfFlights equal to flightCount. And you should use List instead of array to store the Flight and Airport

Answer (score 0):

Better style to have your Read methods accept a file name and return a List or array (where the size of the collection is your `Count` value):

```
public static IList<Flight> ReadFlightFile(string filePath)
{
    var result = new List<Flight>();
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        string[] flightArray = line.Split(',');

        result.Add(new Flight(int.Parse(flightArray[0]), flightArray[1], int.Parse(flightArray[2]),
            int.Parse(flightArray[3]), int.Parse(flightArray[4]));

    }
    return result;
}

//Basic Read Method
public static IList<Airport> ReadAirportFile(string filePath)
{
    var result = new List<Airport>();
    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        string[] airportArray = line.Split(',');

        result.Add(new Airport(int.Parse(airportArray[0]), airportArray[1], airportArray[2], 
            int.Parse(airportArray[3]), DateTime.Parse(airportArray[4]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Do that, and you can add this to your other code:

```
static void Main()
{
    var flights = ReadFlightFile("Flight.csv");
    var airport = ReadAirportFile("Airport.csv");   

    if (airport[0].numOfFlights == flights.Count)
    {
        //things match
    }
    else
    {
        //things don't match
    }       

    // rest of your code is down here:

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than you are making it.

To Count the number of lines in Flight.csv, you can use the following:

```
int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("Your/Path/To/Flight.csv").Count();
```

If you have headings you should -1

To get the number of flights in the Airport.csv, just open it, split into an array, and grab the number like so:

```
string[] AirportContents = File.ReadAllText("Your/Path/To/Airport.csv").Split(',');
int flightsToday = Convert.ToInt32(AirportContents[3]);
```

If there are headings you can put the file contents into a List and read the second item[1] (But you didnt put headings in your example so)

Once you have those 2 numbers you can do anything you want with them.